# React and Material UI, is there is a clean way to de-structure props that I am sending to useStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

From the Material docs, this is how we send props to useStyles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  // style rule
  foo: props => ({
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
  }),
  bar: {
    // CSS property
    color: props => props.color,
  },
});
function MyComponent() {
  // Simulated props for the purpose of the example
  const props = { backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white' };
  // Pass the props as the first argument of useStyles()
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={`${classes.foo} ${classes.bar}`} />
}
```

If I turn my style rules into full functions and do it the way we normally do it like this, it will be repetitive

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(
  theme => ({
    drawer(props) {
      const {isNavOpen} = props;
      return {
        width: isNavOpen ? drawerWidth : drawerWidthClosed,
};
    },
    drawerPaper(props) {
      const {isNavOpen} = props;
      return {
        width: isNavOpen ? drawerWidth : drawerWidthClosed,
      };
    },
```

const {isNavOpen} = props; 
is repeated here

Comment: I would recommend using `props.isNavOpen`, like is recommended in the docs, instead of doing destructuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function, which can be used like this, to avoid repetition

```
const styleDrawerWidth = ( isNavOpen) => {
    return isNavOpen ? drawerWidth : drawerWidthClosed
}


export const useStyles = makeStyles(
theme => ({
    drawer(props) {
    const {isNavOpen} = props;
    return {
        width: styleDrawerWidth(isNavOpen),
    };
    },
    drawerPaper(props) {
    const {isNavOpen} = props;
    return {
        width: styleDrawerWidth(isNavOpen),
    };
},
```

Comment: Thank you, Avinash for directing me to the answer! The repetition I was talking about was repeating `const {isNavOpen} = props;`, and it doesn't look like you took care of that. However, with your direction, the answer is to have your function like this `const styleDrawerWidth = ( props) => {
  const { isNavOpen, drawerWidth, drawerWidthClosed } = props;
  return isNavOpen ? drawerWidth : drawerWidthClosed
}`